# Return list of names and email address from outlook to vb.net listbox

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, vb.net-2010, import-contacts

I want to return from outlook, a list of names and email address and populate them in a listbox so that I can select the ones I want.

I'm looking to do this from the users local contact list and also the global address list on an exchange server.

I've seen many examples (Below) and nothing works, so any help would be most welcomed.

Thanks

Graham

I am using

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

for both examples:

```
 Dim itemx As ListViewItem

        'Create an Outlook application.
        Dim oApp As Outlook._Application = New Outlook.Application()

        ' Get the MAPI namespace.
        Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.Session
        ' Get the Global Address List.
        Dim oALs As Outlook.AddressLists = oNS.AddressLists
        Dim oGal As Outlook.AddressList = oALs.Item("Global Address List")

        ' Get all the entries.
        Dim oEntries As Outlook.AddressEntries = oGal.AddressEntries
        ' Get the first user.
        Dim oEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry = oEntries.GetFirst

        For i As Long = 1 To 10 ' Cut down to 100 as I dont want to load the full AB ** Need to Search rather than Loop **
            If oEntries(i).DisplayType = Outlook.OlDisplayType.olUser Then
                itemx = ListView1.Items.Add(oEntries(i).Name)
                itemx.SubItems.Add(oEntries(i).GetExchangeUser.JobTitle)
                itemx.SubItems.Add(oEntries(i).GetExchangeUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber)
                itemx.SubItems.Add(oEntries(i).GetExchangeUser.OfficeLocation)
                itemx.SubItems.Add(oEntries(i).GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress)
                itemx.SubItems.Add(oEntries(i).GetExchangeUser.CompanyName)
                itemx.SubItems.Add(oEntries(i).GetExchangeUser.Alias)
            End If
        Next

        ' Clean up.
        oApp = Nothing
        oNS = Nothing
        oALs = Nothing
        oGal = Nothing
        oEntries = Nothing
        oEntry = Nothing
```

Also tried:

```
' Create Outlook application.
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()
'Get NameSpace and Logon.
Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
'oNS.Logon("Outlook", , False, True) ' TODO:
oNS.Logon("Outlook", Nothing, False, True)
' Get the first contact from the Contacts folder.
Dim cContacts As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items = cContacts.Items
Dim oCt As Outlook.ContactItem

Try
  oCt = oItems.GetFirst()
  ' Display some common properties.
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.FullName)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.Title)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.Birthday)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.CompanyName)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.Department)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.Body)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.FileAs)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.Email1Address)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.BusinessHomePage)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.MailingAddress)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.BusinessAddress)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.OfficeLocation)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.Subject)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(oCt.JobTitle)
  Catch
      ListBox1.Items.Add("an error occurred")
     'Finally

     ' Display
     'oCt.Display(True)
     ' Log off.
     oNS.Logoff()
    ' Clean up.
     oApp = Nothing
     oNS = Nothing
     oItems = Nothing
     oCt = Nothing
  End Try
```

Comment: Please show what you have so far.  Also, you'll run into problems with the Outlook object model guard if you aren't running this from a VSTO addin and using the reference to the Application object provided through that infrastructure.

Comment: It does not have to be a VSTO addin. Any COM addin is trusted. You can also use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language) to avoid the security prompts.

Comment: Edited post to show code, also what is VSTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the sample code in your first example is correct, except for the "Global Address List" access string. Try using 1 as the array index:

```
Dim oGal As AddressList = oALs.Item(1)
```

I was able to access my contacts by doing this.

Comment: Yes that seams to of worked, how can I get the number of returned entries as the code has limited it to 10?

Comment: Also how can I get my personal Contact list and not the Global Address List?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by number of returned entries..? Do you want to know how many there are total? Try either `oEntries.Count` or `oEntries.Length`

Answer (score 0):

Dim oGal As AddressList = oALs.Item(x)  //  <-- x represents each folder, global, contacts, public, ect

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 Dim oGal As Outlook.AddressList = oNS.GetGlobalAddressList
```