# Pull Outlook OfficeLocation using Alias

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, outlook, exchange-server, alias

While referencing [Return list of names and email address from outlook to vb.net listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417429/return-list-of-names-and-email-address-from-outlook-to-vb-net-listbox) I am trying to fill in a ASP:Textbox with the Office Location of the user.

Currently I pull the current logged in user. The user's username on their PC is also their Outlook Alias. With that being said, I am trying to use the username/Alias to pull the Office location within Outlook. I currently have the following issue with my coding:

[image]

```
'get logged in user(works)
  Dim username As String
  Dim User As System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
  User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
  username = User.Identity.Name.Substring(3)

'Office Location of User
   Dim itemx As String

'Create an Outlook application.
   Dim oApp As Outlook._Application = New Outlook.Application()

'Get the MAPI namespace.
   Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.Session
'Get the Global Address List.
   Dim oALs As Outlook.AddressLists = oNS.AddressLists
   Dim oGal As Outlook.AddressList = oALs.Item(1)

'Get all the entries.
   Dim oEntries As Outlook.AddressEntries = oGal.AddressEntries

       For Each entry In oEntries
          If oEntries.GetExchangeUser.Alias = username Then
              itemx = oEntries.GetExchangeUser.OfficeLocation
          End If
       Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main thing that I learned was that you need a password and username to access outlook.

Get user ID from PC (Alias for Outlook):

```
 Dim usernameQuery As String
 Dim UserQ As System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
 UserQ = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
 usernameQuery = User.Identity.Name.Substring(3).ToUpper
 UserText.Text = usernameQuery
```

Then:

Call function like so:

```
'outlook office location **************************************************
    LocationText.Text = GetUserInfo(usernameQuery, "physicaldeliveryofficename")

    'OTHER OPTIONS YOU CAN QUERY
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "mail")
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "givenName")
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "sn")
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "l")
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "st")
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "streetAddress")
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "postalCode")
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "telephoneNumber")
    'Dim svalue As String = GetUserInfo(useraccount, "co")
    'txtName.Text = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "givenName") & " " & GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "sn")
    'txtPhone.Text = GetUserInfo(UserAccount, "telephoneNumber")
    '********************************************************************************
```

Function:

```
Public Function GetUserInfo(ByVal inSAM As String, ByVal inType As String) As String
    Try
        Dim sPath As String = "LDAP://"full_path"/DC="path_value",DC="path_value",DC="path_value" "
        Dim SamAccount As String = Right(inSAM, Len(inSAM) - InStr(inSAM, "\"))
        Dim myDirectory As New DirectoryEntry(sPath, "username", "password") 'pass the user account and password for your Enterprise admin.
        Dim mySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(myDirectory)
        Dim mySearchResultColl As SearchResultCollection
        Dim mySearchResult As SearchResult
        Dim myResultPropColl As ResultPropertyCollection
        Dim myResultPropValueColl As ResultPropertyValueCollection
        'Build LDAP query
        mySearcher.Filter = ("(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" & SamAccount & "))")
        mySearchResultColl = mySearcher.FindAll()
        'I expect only one user from search result
        Select Case mySearchResultColl.Count
            Case 0
                Return "Null"
                Exit Function
            Case Is > 1
                Return "Null"
                Exit Function
        End Select

        'Get the search result from the collection
        mySearchResult = mySearchResultColl.Item(0)

        ''Get the Properites, they contain the usefull info
        myResultPropColl = mySearchResult.Properties

        If myResultPropColl.Contains(inType) Then
            myResultPropValueColl = myResultPropColl.Item(inType)
            Return CStr(myResultPropValueColl.Item(0))
        End If

        'displayname, mail
        'Retrieve from the properties collection the display name and email of the user
        'myResultPropValueColl = myResultPropColl.Item(inType)
        'Return CStr(myResultPropValueColl.Item(0))

    Catch ex As System.Exception

    End Try
    Return "Null"
End Function
```

FYI-

full_path = "value"."value"."value"

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article in MSDN.

As a workaround you may consider using EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. Or just a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI.

Comment: I will look into your suggestions. Thanks!